# 404 errors on javascript when using importmaps in Rails 7 in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import-maps, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm not sure if this is an importmaps issue or something else, but in Rails 7.0.0.alpha2, I'm getting 404 errors on the javascript files.

[image]

Wondering if I'm missing some sort of production "compile" step as it works fine in development.

```rb
# app/javascript/application.js
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"


# app/javascript/controllers/index.js
import { application } from "./application"

import VoteController from "./vote_controller.js"
application.register("vote", VoteController)


# app/javascript/controllers/vote_controller.js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="vote"
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["element"];

  toggle(event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    event.target.classList.add("opacity-100");
    event.target.classList.remove("opacity-0");
  }
}


# config/importmap.rb
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
```

Then in my `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file I'm using `<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>` to include it all.

If I set `config.assets.compile = true` in `production.rb`, the errors go away...but I'm not sure why or if that's fixing the core issue.

Comment: Were you able to find any resolutions for this other than config.assets.compile = true in production? I'm hitting this issue from a Rails 7.0.0.alpha2 app. I upgraded to 7.0.0.rc1 and still have the issue in prod on Heroku.

Comment: @ianneub Unfortunately not. :(

Comment: Same problem, same "solution." Brand new Rails RC1 installation.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **Rails 7.0.0+ (stable version)**, you **no longer** need to run `rails stimulus:manifest:update` (when using **import maps**) nor need to import each controller individually.

So replace whatever you have in your `app/javascript/controllers/index.js` with the following:

```js
// Import and register all your controllers from the importmap under controllers/*

import { application } from "controllers/application"

// Eager load all controllers defined in the import map under controllers/**/*_controller
import { eagerLoadControllersFrom } from "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
eagerLoadControllersFrom("controllers", application)

// Lazy load controllers as they appear in the DOM (remember not to preload controllers in import map!)
// import { lazyLoadControllersFrom } from "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
// lazyLoadControllersFrom("controllers", application)
```

The above code was copied from https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails/blob/main/lib/install/app/javascript/controllers/index_for_importmap.js.

Answer (score 1):

With Rails 7.0.0 the `app/javascript/controllers/index.js` has been modified. I have found a couple of different ways to fix the issue.

First try changing your `import { application }` line to import from `controllers/application`, like this:

```
import { application } from "controllers/application"
```

Then modify each specific controller import's `from` parameter to look like: `"controllers/name_controller"`.

---

Optionally:

Remove the individual imports for each controller and use:

```
// Eager load all controllers defined in the import map under controllers/**/*_controller
import { eagerLoadControllersFrom } from "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
eagerLoadControllersFrom("controllers", application)
```

Or this:

```
// Lazy load controllers as they appear in the DOM (remember not to preload controllers in import map!)
import { lazyLoadControllersFrom } from "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
lazyLoadControllersFrom("controllers", application)
```

---

This seems to have fixed it for me. Curiously the `rails stimulus:manifest:update` command will replace it with the old style that doesn't work.

More info and discussion on root cause:
https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails/issues/87